# How to get all documents and hide this which are expired if they are defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, mongoid3

I want to hide past events if they are defined and get all other. How to show all documents even if :once_at is nil and if :once_at is defined then hide these ones which are expired?

My recent approach, shows only events with defined :once_at, (I tryed with :once_at => nil, but without results):

```
default_scope where(:once_at.gte => Date.today)
```

or (also not working)

```
default_scope excludes(:once_at.lte => Date.today)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When do you think `Date.today` is evaluated? If you say this:

```
default_scope where(:once_at.gte => Date.today)
```

`Date.today` will be evaluated when the class is being loaded. This is almost never what you want to happen, you usually want `Date.today` to be evaluated when the default scope is used and the usual way to make that happen is to use a proc or lambda for the scope:

```
default_scope -> { where(:once_at.gte => Date.today) }
```

The next problem is what to do about documents that don't have a `:once_at` or those with an explicit `nil` in `:once_at`. `nil` won't be greater than today so you'd best check your conditions separately with an `:$or` query:

```
default_scope -> do
  where(
    :$or => [
      { :once_at     => nil        },
      { :once_at.gte => Date.today }
    ]
  )
end
```